# emacs: Can I stop js2-mode's syntax check?

Tags: javascript, emacs

Maybe that's a simple question: Can I stop js2-mode's syntax check? How ?

It seems it slows down the emacs process.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried byte compiling the source (`byte-compile-file js2-mode.el`)? Performance is terrible if you haven't.

Comment: @wvxvw Yes, it does. I haven't try flymake and jslint. But js2-mode seems does what jslint should do.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I tried. But ... maybe that's my broken notepad. And auto-complete seems doesn't work under js2-mode's syntax check ?

Comment: @wvxvw Odd to me too. You use original js-mode when writing javascript or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, no, you can't. You could turn off the parser, but it would break most of the other stuff.

If you just want `js2-mode`-like indentation, you can use its indentation function with `js-mode`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (require 'js2-mode)
            (setq indent-line-function 'js2-indent-line)))
```